# What is the appropriate flag for this poor answer (if any)?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers

I think it will be immediately obvious to any user that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537825/why-there-is-no-binary-distribution-for-ocaml-on-win64/30811781#30811781) is wholly without merit; it is certainly opinionated and subjective, and does not reference any factual information or source material.

So far I have only down-voted the answer.  I was struggling to figure out if this should be flagged, and what the appropriate flag would be.

- I'm pretty sure "Not an answer" would be inappropriate since it does respond directly to the question (although perhaps it could be argued that it would be more appropraite as a comment).
- I'm not sure if "Very low quality" applies here.
- "Rude or abusive" is a very tempting choice, but I know that flag can be treated with extreme prejudice and I'm not clear as to whether this post really "crosses the line" into that territory.

I'd appreciate your thoughts on if any of these flags would be appropriate, or if this is considered the kind of question that "just needs to be down-voted."

Comment: The answer is to a very old question. It is also incorrect. https://ocaml.org/docs/install.html#OCPWINSelfContainedOCamlforWindows says "OCPWin is a self-contained binary distribution of OCaml for Windows. It supports both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows platforms,". However it also says "Note: The link for OCPWin has been removed due to an issue waiting to be solved."

Comment: I have voted to close the "question" as opinion based.

Answer (score 15):

If anything I would go with Very Low Quality.

The answer reads more like a comment, and even as a comment it wouldn't be very useful.

That said the question seems a little suspect to me. It seems to be asking:

> Why is language X missing feature Y?

No one, apart for the original designers, can offer a real answer to the question; so it should probably be closed.

Comment: This particular question is pretty bad, but I've seen some good Java rationale questions answered by Brian Goetz or based on the Java designer mailing list archives. Knowing why something was designed the way it was can really help understanding how to use it well.

Comment: "The answer reads more like a comment" would have me leaning more towards the "Not an answer" flag.  Although I agree it is certainly lacking in quality as well!  On the bright side, the answer seems to be gone now (and in fact the whole question was put on hold),